# hide access directory unless direct link

Tags: html, database, .htaccess

I have a website thats live and another (for amends/approval) that is in a subdirectory called 'approval'. The idea being that once its approved I replace the live site. Is there a way to restrict access to this directory unless you have a direct link - maybe through .htaccess? Any other suggestions regarding protocol for this scenario? Thanks!

Comment: Create a subdomain which is basically a virtual host, and restrict access to that subdomain using http auth.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried something with .htacces.
You can make a 403 error page. You can't go to a directory unless you have a link.

Make a .htacces file with the following  code:

```
## Error Page
ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
Options -Indexes
```

the `##` means that the line is hidden, for text

ErrorDocument 403 gives the place of the 403 error file. You can also type this: `/errors/403.html`

`Options -Indexes` blocks the directory's

I hope that it works for you

Comment: Thanks for that - this may seem like a silly question but how do I know if this has worked? Obviously the URL to that directory works?

Comment: Example: I have some images on my website. http://wouterschaeffer.nl/images You can't see them. But when you type a specific URL: http://wouterschaeffer.nl/images/2.jpg You will see the image